# Amazon CloudSearch multiple search domains

Tags: amazon-web-services

Can I have multiple search domains in one instance CloudSearch? I can't seem to find this information in manual and it obviously affects the cost of hosting.

Comment: I can't create the tag amazon-cloudsearch, but it's something to do for an user with more reputation. :)